# WPF XAML - stacking circular items in a Triangle? is it possible?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml

overflowians,

I am trying to represent a 3 tiered Navigation menu that are inside a Triangle (which is actually invisible) and was wondering if there is any way of being able to stack a list of items using styling inside a triangular path, and making it wrap the items correctly.

I can not seem to find a good way, or if it is even possible.

i just would like to make this as dynamic as possible so that i can reuse it a whole lot of different places that i need it for.

***EDIT *****

I also need to be able to rotate the 3 items around somehow? but i also need to be able to rotate the 3 items around, its a navigation menu system, so i want to have the naviation menu items as list items which i can template.

Thanks

Robbie

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can use a path listbox. Check this out http://www.microsoft.com/design/toolbox/tutorials/pathlistbox/

Answer (score 0):

if you need to place only 3 items, and if this number will be a constant, it's really possible with `<Style>` or `<Template>` and `DataBinding`.

Comment: Would i then be able to rotate the 3 items around somehow? i should have explained in my top post and will edit the post actually, but i also need to be able to rotate the 3 items around, its a navigation menu system, so i want to have the naviation menu items as list items which i can template.

Comment: yes. you can use `RotateTransformation`, or just using array : `MyArray[3] {Item1, Item2, Item3}` and replace Items as you want, if I understand your rotation right.